# Can you modify your own page tables (OS related)?

Tags: operating-system

I am currently learning about Virtual Memory within the OS. I recently learned that access rights are stored in the page tables and so I am wondering if you can modify your own page tables? Does the hardware enforce protection from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can modify your page tables—to some degree. Most operating system have system services to allow you to map and unmap pages to your address space (thus modifying your page tables).

Because page tables are stored in the system address space invariably with access limited to kernel mode, you have to modify the page tables in kernel mode. That means doing it through a system service that executes in kernel mode.

Of course you are limited to the types of modification you can make by the system services.

Answer (score 1):

No, you (as user code) cannot directly modify the page tables for your processs, or any other process.

The page tables are manages exclusively by the kernel. They are stored in physical memory which is not mapped into userspace.

The hardware  (specifically the MMU) enforces this protection just as it protects all of the kernel data and code.

Comment: What if you write your own kernel module?

Comment: If you write a kernel module, then you run with the same permissions as the kernel itself.